# Is GCC attribute(packed) allowed on a whole struct?

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer

Since beginning of the times I've used to believe that __attribute__((packed)) can be put on a struct or typedef, like that:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    uint8_t   m1;
    uint16_t  m2;
    uint8_t   m3;
    uint32_t  m4;
    uint8_t   m5;
} junk;
```

But then someone pointed out that this obvious usage is not documented in the recent gcc manuals, for already several releases.
Rather it says (in [v.12](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Common-Variable-Attributes.html#Common-Variable-Attributes)): "The [packed] attribute **does not apply to non-member objects**."
A whole struct is not a member object, correct?
So is the above example legal, or does it rely on UB (that can bite later)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above example is legal. The documentation that you linked to is a listing of *variable attributes*, which are attached to individual variables, not whole structures. When the documentation says that the attribute "does not apply to non-member objects", it is saying that it does not apply to non-member *variables*. Nothing on that page applies to the usage of the `packed` attribute shown here.

Instead, your example of using the `packed` attribute is using a *type attribute*, which happens to have the same name as the `packed` variable attribute; see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html) for the documentation. `packed` is one of the attributes listed there; besides the name and somewhat related functionality (of controlling how fields are arranged in a structure), these two attributes are not related to each other.

Comment: Is there any difference between `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` and `__attribute__ ((packed))`?

Comment: @pmor No difference for gcc.  TL;DR omitting underscores on attribute names is allowed. (For other compilers - not sure)

Comment: @ddbug Thanks. Another related example: to my knowledge GCC supports both `__asm volatile` and `__asm__ __volatile__`. I guess that they are functionally equivalent.